# A Database Error Occurred table doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

After update codeignitor 3.1.11 there is a database error like

**A Database Error Occurred**

Error Number: 1146

Table 'db_bill_app.Users' doesn't exist

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `db_PaymentHistory` AS `PH` LEFT JOIN 
Users AS U ON PH.fk_UserGlCode = U.intGlCode LEFT JOIN ManageAcc AS MA ON 
PH.fk_UserGlCode = MA.intGlCode
```

Filename: D:/wamp/www/project/alpha/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: is there `Users` table in your `db_bill_app` DB? Please check the name is it in upper case or in lower?

Comment: Looks like the table `db_bill_app.Users` doesn't exist

Comment: yes there is a cuc_Users name

Comment: Then, use `cuc_Users` instead of `Users`

Comment: but i use db prefix in config file.

Comment: use `Users` is in backtick in your query.

Comment: i dint do that bcs i use in whole project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution after lots of try

**system/database/DB_query_builder.php**

in this line

```
 $this->qb_join[] = $join = $type.'JOIN '.$table.$cond;
```

i have add some code like:

```
$word = $this->dbprefix;
    if(strpos($table, $word) !== false){
     $table = $table;   
    }else{
        $table = $word.$table;
    }
```

to add manually prefix before table name.. enjoy

Comment: Which version of CI did you upgrade from?

Comment: my ci version is 3.1.11

Comment: So you hadn't upgraded from an older CI Version? This project was started using CI 3.1.11?

Comment: Ok you upgraded Your CI from ?????? to 3.1.11. Only you can fill in the question marks. So what version did you upgrade from?

Comment: Ok you upgraded Your CI from  2.2.6 -  upgrade from 3.1.11